# jQuery/Ajax content not appearing/loading in Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, explorer

I have been working on a template using almost all jquery/javascript. Mostly I am learning jquery/javascript. My site is at http://chainery.comoj.com. The site works well in FF and Safari but alas, IE doesn't load the first page. The ajax indicator shows up and that is it. On the first page it loads data from an xml file and displays it. I thought I had stayed away from stuff that was sketchy in IE but I missed something. The 'product' pages do load all of the content correctly but on the left side of the text should be an image. I am hoping this is the same problem. I know I am short on info here and am willing to post whatever is needed, but I just don't know where to begin.

Thank you very much,
                      Todd

Comment: Would be helpful if you point us at the script where you load the content, so we dont need to study the whole dozen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In template_xml.js, you're dying on line 170.

```
$("title").text($(this).find("pageName").text());
```

This jquery bug [is discussed here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2755).

Their solution is:

> The correct cross-browser way to change the document title is through the document.title property.

And they've marked the bug as "wontfix".
Hope this helps.

BWI, for anyone else searching, the error that you see is:

> Unexpected call to method or property access. Line: 113 Symbol: 193
>   Code: 0 URI-code: / jquery-1.4.3.min.js

For those curious how I tracked it down:

- In IE, hit F12 to bring up debugger.
- Click on Script Tab
- Click "Start Debugging" (page reloads)
- In right pane, click "Call Stack"
- Start going down the entries, until I stop seeing low level jQuery code, and start seeing the user's code.
- Entry is: `$("title").text($(this).find("pageName").text());` (which agrees with what I read when I did a quick google for the error that I mentioned above.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a Mac guy but now know how to do minor debugging with IE.