# Debug JavaScript in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Currently I am debugging my JavaScript using Firebug for Firefox.  Is there anyway to debug javascript in Visual Studio 2010?  The JavaScript isn't part of any Visual Studio project, it's just a .js file that will be linked to a static HTML page (it's to debug school assignments).

I did try searching and the results weren't any more recent than around a year ago.  I'm hoping something has changed or there is a better workflow than notepad++ for HTML/JavaScript and Firebug for debugging.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the JavaScript debugger keyword in IE.

```
function onClickRow(detailUrl) {
    debugger;
}
```

When run your page in IE, a debug window will pop up, then select Visual Studio 11.

Comment: It works in current Chrome. You just need to have developer tools open.

Answer (score 16):

To use debug in Internet Explorer, you need perform these steps:

- enable script debugging in IE (go to Internet options->advanced->browsing and uncheck 'Disable script debugging')
- select view->external script debugger->break on next statement

When next javascript statement will be reached, IE will show standard windows debugger selection dialog, when you can select instance of visual studio.

**Update**:
With visual studio you can attach to browser process(e.g. iexplore.exe) and then debug

Answer (score 6):

This question gets a lot of views so for the sake of completeness I just wanted to mention that I've been using [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) for a while now.  It's been working great for me and is what I recommend now when people ask me this same question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only in IE.  Basically just create a web-page project and hit run.  It'll launch IE in debugger mode.

Answer (score 1):

disable option from Internet Options like here : http://www.mayanksrivastava.com/2010/02/debugging-java-script-in-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

If you installed VS 2012 and then uninstalled it, you may need to Re-Install Visual Studio 2010.

Error you may get when trying to debug JavaScript:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to attach to the crashing process. The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered. Repair your Visual Studio 2010 installation, or run 'regsvr32.exe "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\pdm.dll"'.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try giving it a shot in IE, I posted about using the js debugger here:
[jQuery/Ajax content not appearing/loading in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280093/jquery-ajax-content-not-appearing-loading-in-explorer/5280244#5280244)