# Do we have a good javascript debugger?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103155/javascript-debugger)

Is there any way to debug javascript. I found many addons on mozilla but I am not able to use them properly because of limited documents. Can any one point me a good debugger on which I could rely on. Thanks In advance.

Comment: ?, what are you talking about. Firefox maybe give bad performance but Firebug is solid tool.

Comment: here is Venkman https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Venkman and firebug http://getfirebug.com/javascript/

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/javascript/ detail for "
 how to debug "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/103155/352796)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is a tool that help you to debug javascript inside browser. You can choose Chrome dev tool either (depend on what you love to use)

If you don't love to do javascript debug inside browser then I can suggest you to use Visual web developer  which is freely available and make you able to debug your code from IDE.

read this [Debug JavaScript in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413937/debug-javascript-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 4):

Modern browsers *already have debuggers built in*:

IE

- F12 Developer tools (built-in, IE9+)
- DebugBar toolbar (third-party, < IE9)

Firefox

- Firebug addon (third-party)

Safari & Chrome

- Webkit developer tools (built-in)

Opera

- Dragonfly (built-in)

Additionally, Firebug also comes in a script version Firebug lite which can be used on any browser. Just add the script in the head before anything else and remove it during production.